# How to replace number in this string using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Can someone tell me how to replace the number "2" with another number in this string"? For example, if it's a 2, it should be a 3, if it's a 3 it should be a 4, etc.

Please note that the number can be any number from 1 through 5.

```
/img/tmp/2_th.jpg
```

Comment: Replace it with what?

Comment: See my modified question above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing all occurrences of a string in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `String#replace`:

```
s.replace(/\d+(?=_)/, "replaced");
```

To replace any number from 1-5 use:

```
s.replace(/[1-5](?=_)/, "replaced");
```

Here `(?=_)` is used a positive lookahead which makes sure match a number which is followed by underscore `_`.

**UPDATE: Based on your edit you can use this code to increment matched number by 1:**

```
s.replace(/([1-5])(?=_)/, function(n) {return parseInt(n)+1;});
```

[**Read More About Lookarounds in Regex**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Well not "just". You should probably explain to OP the lookahead.

Comment: @dystroy: Thanks for your comment, I started typing some explanation then got distracted by a colleague :P

Comment: @anubhava, Thanks! Your answer is perfect and I will select it as the answer when the time is up. I know this isn't directly related to my original question, but can you also tell me how to get the "2" and save it as a variable?

Comment: Yes I edited my code to give you answer of incrementing the matched number by 1 (see UPDATE section)

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your question that you want to replace any number by the following one (*" if it's a 2, it should be a 3, if it's a 3 it should be a 4"*).

Then you can do this :

```
var input = "/img/tmp/2_th.jpg";
var output = input.replace(/\d+/g,function(s){ return +s+1 })
```

Result :

```
"/img/tmp/3_th.jpg"
```